# how to write the sql statement for it?

Tags: sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to write the sql statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642323/how-to-write-the-sql-statement)

```
IncidentReportid                  Interviewers                 MainInterviewer 
18 :Name/nric/Desg/iunit/remark: NAME2/inric/iDesg/iunit/iremark:                nric
19 :irank/inric/iDesg/iunit/iremark:irank1/inric1/iDesg1/iunit1/iremark1:        inric  
20 :irank4/inric4/iDesg4/iunit4/iremark4:irank5/inric5/iDesg5/iunit5/iremark5:   inric5
21 :irank7/inric7/iDesg7/iunit7/iremark7:irank8/inric8/iDesg8/iunit8/iremark8:   inric7
23 :irank9/inric9/iDesg9/iunit9/iremark9:irank6/inric6/iDesg6/iunit6/iremark6:   inric9
24 :RankOfAddison/aNRIC/aInstructor/aUnit/aRemark:RankOfNang/nNRIC/nInstructor/nUnit/nRemark:  aNRIC
```

Eg. I have the table as above and i wanna get the data as following. thanks. :)

```
IncidentReportid                Interviewers       MainInterviewer             
18                                Name             nric
19                                irank            inric                 
20                                irank5           inric5               
21                                irank7           inric7                 
23                                irank9           inric9                
24                                RankOfAddison    aNRIC
```

The main thing is that I want to get the 'interviewers' name depend on the Main Interviewer' NRIC.

Comment: Please format your example data better.

Answer (score 0):

```
select IncidentReportid,
       SUBSTRING(Interviewers,2,CHARINDEX('/',Interviewers)-2) as Interviewers,
       MainInterviewer
from Table
```